# why is my project being shown like this in android studio? How do I get back to the project structure?

Tags: android

My project is being shown like this in the android studio panel.  I need to see the proper project structure. Any help would be appreciated.

.gitignore

build.gradle

gradle.properties

gradlew

gradlew.bat

settings.gradle

External Libraries

Comment: I think you forgot to attach the image

Answer (score 0):

only those file are showing which you mentioned or there are more files showing please share a snapshot of that issue.

You can try by going on file and then on other settings and default project structure this may work if not than try the other option default settings.

Answer (score 0):

Check this screenshot:
[image]

Click on the red highlighted part, and select the mode whatever suits you better. I prefer the one named "Project" which is selected right now. My source code and all app data is in this "app" directory which is highlighted blue.